# UICollectionView - ListView and GridView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I need to create a view which contains image and labels, and can view in list view or grid view. Is `UICollectionView` can do this? or any suggestion on how to do this? And every item/view is clickable. What is the best way to do this.

Comment: For grid `UICollectionView` is good and easy then `UITableView`to use because you can reuse cell. for list view you can use either `UICollectionView` or `UITableView`. both are good to use because of reusablility.

Comment: @xed hacker if you want ListView(UITableView) You need Custom Cell

\flow this http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by two ways

1) using `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`: [UITableView](http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/) for displaying your content as list and [UICollectionView](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/) for showing as grid.you have to switch between these two views as your view style(list/grid) changes.

2) using `UICollectionView` Alone :

-> for grid [UICollectionView](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/) with multiple columns and rows.

-> for list UICollectionView with single column and multiple rows.adjust inset values of collection view item

Comment: If I'm going to use `UITableView` and `UIColletionView`, and switch between the two views, the position of scrollbar will change right? Right now I'm using `UIScrollView` but seems not the proper way. and I'm not really familiar with `UITableView`. I'm having a hard time on adjusting the sizes of the image.